# Implement Conway's Game of Life in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The way I have to implement this game is by reading in a file of ones and zeros and then determining the next generation and updating the board accordingly.  This is what I have so far.  I am required to use the five methods given, so I cant change that, I can add some if necessary but I can't get rid of any.  I don't know how I'm supposed to update the existing integer array in the update array by only passing it one 2d integer array.  I tried writing the conditionals in the main method to solve this but I'm completely stuck.  Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Proj5{
    public static void main(String[] args)throws FileNotFoundException, NumberFormatException{
    int[][] grid = readBoard("life4.txt");
    System.out.print(boardDisplay(grid));
    System.out.println();
    int rows = grid.length;
    int cols = grid[0].length;
    int[][] temp = new int [rows][cols];


    //Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbors dies of loneliness
    //Any live cell with more than three live neighbors dies of overcrowding
    //Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbors comes to life
    //Any live cell with two or three neighbors stays alive
    //Any dead cell that does not have exactly three live neighbors remains dead 
    for(int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j < cols - 1; j++){
            int friends = neighbors(grid, rows, cols);
            System.out.print(friends);
            if(grid[i][j] == 1 && friends < 2){
                temp[i][j] = 0;
            }
            if(grid[i][j] == 1 && friends > 3){
                temp[i][j] = 0;
            }
            /*else if(grid[i][j] == 0 && friends == 3){
                grid[i][j] = 1;
            }
            else if(grid[i][j] == 1 && (friends == 2 || friends == 3)){
                grid[i][j] = 1;
            }*/
        }
    }
    System.out.print(boardDisplay(temp));



}
//This method should read the specified input file, read it into an int[][] array, and return that array.
public static int[][] readBoard(String filename)throws FileNotFoundException, NumberFormatException{
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    int rows = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine());  
    int columns = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine());
    int[][] board = new int [rows + 2][columns + 2];

    for(int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++){
        String newLine = inFile.nextLine();
        String[] elements = newLine.split("");
        for(int j = 1; j < columns - 1; j++){
            board[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(elements[j]);                
        }
    }
    return board;
} 
//This method should return the String representing the cells array (so that it would print as a grid if printed).
public static String boardDisplay(int[][] cells){
    String st = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < cells.length - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < cells[0].length - 1; j++){
            if(cells[i][j] == 0){
                st += ".";
            }
            else{
                st += "*";
            }
        }
        st += "\n";
    }
    return st;
}
//This method should return the number of live neighbors that position (row,col) has in the cells array.
public static int neighbors(int[][] cells, int row, int col){
    int counter = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < row - 1; i++){
        for(int j = 1; j < col - 1; j++){           
            if(cells[i-1][j-1] == 1){
                counter++;
            }
            if(cells[i-1][j] == 1){
                counter++;
            }
            if(cells[i-1][j+1] == 1){
                counter++;
            }
            if(cells[i][j-1] == 1){
                counter++;
            }
            if(cells[i][j+1] == 1){
                counter++;
            }
            if(cells[i+1][j-1] == 1){
                counter++;
            }
            if(cells[i+1][j] == 1){
                counter++;
            }
            if(cells[i+1][j+1] == 1){
                counter++;
            }
            System.out.print(counter);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }           
    return counter;
} 
//This method should return the next generation of the cells array.
public static int[][] update(int[][] cells){ 
    for(int i = 1; i < rows - 1; i++){
        for int(j = 1; j < cols - 1; j++){
            if(grid[i][j] == 1 && friends < 2){
                grid[i][j] == update(grid);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

the life4.txt file looks like this:

25
77
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000011111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000010001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000110001100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000001010001010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000110001100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000010001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000011111000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score 0):

Your `update` method needs to receive an array, make a temp array, set that temp array's data based on the received array, and return the temp array. So move the code that updates the array out of your main method, and put it into update.

Then, in your main method, read the original grid exactly as you do already, and then call update repeatedly:

```
int[][] grid = readBoard("life4.txt");
// println original grid
System.out.println(boardDisplay(grid));

for(int i=0; i < 10; i++){ // 10 iterations
    grid = update(grid);
    System.out.println(boardDisplay(grid));
}
```